# How does one set up an automatic LESS compiler on IIS 7.5?

Tags: less, iis-7.5

Could someone help explain how to set up automatic LESS compiling on IIS?

I need it to watch a folder and recompile when any less files, or their imports, are updated - much like what Koala App or Winless does but using the native LESS compiler and no GUI.

Comment: Rather than recompiling on a file change level, have you considered a dynamic compiling approach with caching? [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) makes this pretty seamless.

Comment: @Bensmind Unfortunately dotless appears to be a dead project.  It certainly isn't getting enough attention to rely on it for production work.


   As to this question, I have leaned on Gulp which is outside IIS but a better supported ecosystem for this type of thing.

Comment: Given that their last nuget publish was at the end of last month, I would disagree on it being a dead project. If you can source that claim, I would definitely be interested. I have used dotless on numerous projects over the last 2 years that are currently in production with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: @bensmind We evaluated in 2014 and there wasn't any updates for close to a year. Great to see some action again as I'm sure it will work for some people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the best answer is to get native and install Node then use [Grunt](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-less), [Gulp](https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less) or even just [scripts](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/why-we-should-stop-using-grunt/)